# wand.exceptions.MissingDelegateError: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

Hello i am using python in combination with **imagemagick** to convert an pdf to a image (jpeg). I installed ImageMagick and the Python Wand module.

when i run the script in Windows 10 it runs perfectly but when i run it under Ubuntu 20.xx i get the following error as response:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "wandExample.py", line 2, in
>
> pdf = wi(filename="data/Lucas_Mur.pdf", resolution=300)   File "/home/erik_hoeven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wand/image.py",
> line 8636, in **init**
> self.read(filename=filename)   File "/home/erik_hoeven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wand/image.py",
> line 9230, in read
> self.raise_exception()   File "/home/erik_hoeven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wand/resource.py",
> line 230, in raise_exception
> raise e wand.exceptions.MissingDelegateError: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562

```
from wand.image import Image as wi
pdf = wi(filename="data/Lucas_Mur.pdf", resolution=300)
pdfimage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
i=1
for img in pdfimage.sequence:
    page = wi(image=img)
    page.save(filename=str(i)+".jpg")
    i +=1
```

For the installation of ImageMagick under Ubuntu 20.xxx i executed the following statement:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
./configure` 
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
sudo apt-get install -y ghostscript-x
```

when i test imagemagick by using `magick -version` the result is:

> Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-31 Q16 x86_64 2020-09-27
> https://imagemagick.org Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
> License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher
> DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)  Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig
> freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib

I am getting also an error message when i execute the imagemagick command:

```
convert Lucas_Mur.pdf Output.jpg
```

> convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562. convert: no images defined` Output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.

Can you please help to solve this error and explain why i receive this!

Comment: Have you installed ghostscript?

Comment: No!! What is nesserly to install ?

Comment: For PDF, ImageMagick will need ghostscript as a delegate.

Comment: Ok, i executed sudo apt-get install -y ghostscript-x but still get the same result

Comment: Try adding the `-verbose` flag to the convert command, and see what ghostscript command is failing. `convert -verbose Lucas_Mur.pdf Output.jpg`